# Android custom seekbar not drawing in < 3.0

Tags: android, seekbar

I've created a custom seekbar for an app. It works fine on all newer devices, but it doesn't appear in the UI when I try it on an older device, with android v 2.3 to be specific. It still works - when I touch the blank space where the seekbar should draw, I see the values changing in a linked TextView, but it just doesn't draw. I'm probably using a method which isnt supported in 2.3, but i cant figure out which. Does anybody have an idea? Here is the code:

```
    public class CustomSeekBar extends SeekBar {

    private Paint selected, unselected;
    private int halfSize = 15;
    private RectF position;
    private final Bitmap thumbImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img_fragment_settings_seekbar_thumb);

    public CustomSeekBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        selected = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        selected.setColor(Color.argb(0xFF, 0x29, 0x80, 0xb9));
        selected.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        unselected = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        unselected.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
        selected.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        position = new RectF();
        this.setMax(12);
    }

    public CustomSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        selected = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        selected.setColor(Color.argb(0xFF, 0x29, 0x80, 0xb9));
        selected.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        unselected = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        unselected.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
        selected.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        position = new RectF();
        this.setMax(12);
    }

    public CustomSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        selected = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        selected.setColor(Color.argb(0xFF, 0x29, 0x80, 0xb9));
        selected.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        unselected = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        unselected.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
        selected.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        position = new RectF();
        this.setMax(12);
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float halfHeight = (canvas.getHeight())*.5f;
        position.set(
            0, 
            halfHeight-2, 
            getWidth(),
            halfHeight+2); 

        canvas.drawRect(position, selected);

        if(getProgress() !=0 ){
            position.right = getWidth() * getProgress()/12;
            canvas.drawRect(position, unselected);
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(thumbImage, (getWidth()- thumbImage.getWidth()) * getProgress()/12  , halfHeight - thumbImage.getHeight()/2, null);

        //super.onDraw(canvas);
        // this is intentional, I don't want to call super
    }

    public int getDotsSize() {
        return halfSize*2;
    }

    public void setDotsSize(int dotsSize) {
        this.halfSize = dotsSize/2;
    }
```

}

Then I simply insert it in XML:

```
                    <com.xxx.custom_views.CustomSeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/sb_set_interval"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fragment_settings_interactive_elements_bottom_margin"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:max="12"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progerss"
                    android:thumb="@drawable/img_fragment_settings_seekbar_thumb" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: you shouldn't do that,  don't extend a SeekBar to make it custom, what you should do instead is to create a custom Drawable

Comment: @pskink You mean setting android:progressDrawable? Cause that doesn't work for me as I need the bar to extend itself from one side of the view to the other, without leaving half thumb width on each side of the view blank. And extending the seekbar seemed very practical to me as I need its onProgressChanged method, I don't know how I would do that myself from scratch.

Comment: just extend Drawable clsss